# Sending popup message in the middle of session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wonder is there a way to send users an alert message in the middle of a session? for example when a transaction status changes from "process" to "succeed" I want the user to know it in the middle of their session.

I hope my question can be answered using jQuery AJAX. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes it can be done with AJAX and PHP, You need to attempt to do this yourself. I think people will agree when i say we're not here to write code for you, if you want that hire one of us! Take a tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/

Comment: may be not you @Edward but i'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using Comet for things like this. I assume you meant that you want to alert the user without them having performed some action? The atmosphere project has a javascript component that can be used client side to achieve this, but it will also require some support from your back-end.

Comment: ya that's true, I want them receive that kind of alert. Can you give me more of the explaination, because i'm not too familiar with "Comet". can this be done only with javascript ajax. thanks for the respon.

Comment: Comet is often called reverse ajax, you make an ajax call that has no timeout, and the server also does not timeout or close the connection. With the connection open, the server can arbitrarily send data to the client, this is known as "push technology". You CAN do this manually with an XmlHttpRequest, or with jQuery, but it can be quite complex, so libraries with good implementations will make your life so much easier. Check out the cometD project: http://cometd.org/